# React Native Swiper - Rendering components in second page before first page

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper, react-native-chart-kit

I am facing an issue with using React Native Swiper (https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper). When I render my View which wraps the Swiper component, all the components inside the Swiper component are displayed on the screen for a split second, before the first page is shown.

```
import React from 'react'
import CircularProgress from 'react-native-circular-progress-indicator';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import { BarChart } from 'react-native-chart-kit'

const FillPercentCircle = ({ fillPercent }) => {
    const getColour = () => {
        // red
        if (fillPercent >= 75) return '#FF0000'
        // orange
        if (fillPercent >= 50) return '#f39c12'
        // green
        return '#03AC0A'
    }

    const data = {
        labels: ["5am", "6am", "7am", "8am", "9am", "10am", "11am", "12pm", "1pm", "2pm", "3pm", "4pm",],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [70, 100, 20, 45, 28, 80, 99, 43, 30, 95, 85,]
            },
        ]
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.bottomPanel}>
            <Swiper loadMinimal={true} loadMinimalSize={1}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.fillPanelText}>
                        Fill Chart
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.circle}>
                        <CircularProgress
                            value={fillPercent}
                            valueSuffix={'%'}
                            activeStrokeColor={getColour()}
                            textColor={getColour()}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <BarChart
                    style={{
                        marginTop:20,
                        marginBottom:20,
                        borderRadius: 0,
                        // alignSelf: 'center',
                    }}
                    data={data}
                    fromZero={true}
                    width={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.95}
                    height={Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.25}
                    yAxisSuffix="%"
                    yAxisInterval={25}
                    chartConfig={{
                        barPercentage: 0.35,
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                        backgroundGradientFrom: "white",
                        backgroundGradientTo: "white",
                        fillShadowGradient: 'black',
                        fillShadowGradientOpacity: 1,
                        decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
                        labelColor: () => 'black',
                        color: () => 'transparent',
                        style: {
                            borderRadius: 16,
                            marginVertical:8,
                            padding:5,
                            paddingRight:0,
                        },
                    }}
                    verticalLabelRotation={315}
                />
            </Swiper>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Basically, the second page in the Swiper (BarChart) displays on the screen for a split second, before the View (containing CircularProgress). Appreciate the assistance!

Also, if there is a way to increase the margin between the labels and x-axis of the BarChart component from react-native-chart-kit, please let me know. I can't seem to figure it out.